# Use proguard to ONLY remove log statements

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I want to use proguard to only remove log statements, but now my application crashes when it is started. I am not too familiar with proguard, but I guess I have to add in some lines to keep my other classes to be fine.

This is my proguard-project.txt:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }

#ProGuard may remove code that it thinks you don't use such as:
#a class that is referenced only in the AndroidManifest.xml file
#a method called from JNI
#dynamically referenced fields and methods
#-keep public class <MyClass>
```

How would I go about adding a statement that will "disregard" proguard for all of my other classes? I just want to make sure that the removal of the logging works. I will then concentrate on obfuscation later down the road.

I am trying this, but I get an error when exporting:

```
-keep class com.finesspro.gui** { * }
```

Answer (score 2):

In proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn **
-target 1.7
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/allocation/variable
-keep class **
-keepclassmembers class *{*;}
-keepattributes *


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {

    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);

}
```

---

In gradle.build

```
buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to keep you classes: (different syntax with the ";")

```
-keep class com.finesspro.** { *; }
```

And you should try the  **proguard-android-optimize.txt** instead of this, where the optimalization is turned on!
After that you can use this also:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

EDIT: If you would like to keep other classes you need to also add them to the proguard file.
For example for the actionbarsherlock:

```
# For ActionbarSherlock
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** {*;}
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

Comment: I keep getting an error when I try to export. I get this in my cole:

Comment: I keep getting an error when I try to export. I get this in my console:2014-01-19 16:19:32 - Camera] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

[2014-01-19 16:19:35 - actionbarsherlock] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
[2014-01-19 16:19:36 - android-switch-backport] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
[2014-01-19 16:19:36 - google-play-services_lib] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

Comment: If you user libs, then you should define their classes in proguard. See my edited answer, where is an example about the actionbarsherlock